# google sheets return values from dropdowns and create new row

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to create a html popup from google sheets that returns the selected option from a dropdown. i have created the html window, passed it an array of variables and converted them to options. I now need to pass the selections back to GAS and use GAS to create a new row on a sheet. This is the GAS code im using and the HTML file:

```js
//Add Standing Order
function addSO() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Customers"));
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Customers"); 
    var list  = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
    var values  = list.toString().split(",");
    var values = JSON.stringify(values);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ResourcesDONTTOUCH"); 
    var list  = sheet.getRange("H:H").getValues();
    var values1  = list.toString().split(",");
    var values1 = JSON.stringify(values1);
    var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('htmlAddSO'); // Modified
    t.values = [values]; // Added
    t.values1 = [values1]; //Added
      html = t.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Add New Standing Order');
}

//Write Standing Order
function writeSO(obj) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Standing Orders"));
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Standing Orders"); 
    sheet.appendRow([obj.selectCustomer, obj.selectProduct, obj.notes]);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
 <form>
 <H2>Select Customer from list</H2>
 <select id="selectCustomer" name="selectCustomer">
    <option>Choose a Customer</option>
</select>
<H2>Select Product</H2>
 <select id="selectProduct" name="selectProduct">
    <option>Choose a Product</option>
</select>
<H2>Notes</H2>
<input type="text" size="50" name="notes" id="notes">
<br>
<br>
     <input type="button" value="OK" onClick="submitorder(this.parentNode);" />
</form>
<script>

var select = document.getElementById("selectCustomer");
var options = <?!= values ?>;
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
var select = document.getElementById("selectProduct");
var options1 = <?!= values1 ?>;
for(var i = 0; i < options1.length; i++) {
    var opt = options1[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}

function submitorder(obj) {
 google.script.run
   .withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();})
   .writeSO(obj);
      }
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Any assistance with this would be super helpful.

TIA

**EDIT**
I have updated the code snippet to a closer working version the previous was a mess. For clarity i need to be able to return the values of the options and the note section back into GAS so i can create and fill a new row on the standing orders sheet

At present i have pulled the ranges from a sheet, split the range and presented them as options in the HTML. I have also made it append the row but at present it appends it blank and not with the options chosen in the html, it also does not pull the "notes" across.

I just need the correct method of returning the variables from html to GAS. Any explanation of how it works would be greatly appreciated for learning purposes.

Comment: Tell us what's happening, and ask a specific question.  The code you posted right now has a syntax error.

Comment: No problem i can clarify. Ive made some changes since posting. Basically i am pulling an array from ranges on a sheet and converting them to options in the html pop up. im trying to make that return the selected options and bit of text which i then write to a new row on the sheet.

Comment: i have updated the original post. to help clarify and clean the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, I suggest moving your scriptlets (`<? ?>` tags) out of the JavaScript and into the HTML.  It is only on rare occasion that I have found need for scriplets inside the JavaScript.  This should eliminate whatever you were trying to accomplish with the `JSON.stringify(values)`.  You should be able to just put an array of values onto the template without using JSON.

Use [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to call your server side function to append the row. You can use the `google.script.host.close` as the success handler.

#### The template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
 <form>
 <H2>Select Customer from list</H2>
 <select id="selectCustomer" name="selectCustomer">
    <option>Choose a Customer</option>
    <? customers.forEach(value => { ?>
         <option value="<?= value ?>"><?= value ?></option>
    <? }) ?>
</select>
<H2>Select Product</H2>
 <select id="selectProduct" name="selectProduct">
    <option>Choose a Product</option>
    <? products.forEach(value => { ?>
      <option value="<?= value ?>"><?= value ?></option>
    <? }) ?>
</select>
<H2>Notes</H2>
<input type="text" size="50" name="notes" id="notes">
<br>
<br>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", onsubmit);
const selectCustomer = document.querySelector("#selectCustomer");
const selectProduct = document.querySelector("#selectProduct");
const notes = document.querySelector('#notes');
function onsubmit() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).append({
    customer: selectCustomer.value,
    product: selectProduct.value,
    notes: notes.value
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Server-side code:

```js
//Add Standing Order
function addSO() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var customersSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Customers"); 
  var customers  = customersSheet
    .getRange("A:A")
    .getValues()
    .flat() // requires V8; turns nested arrays into single array
    .filter(value => value); // removes blanks
  var productsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ResourcesDONTTOUCH");
  var products = productsSheet
    .getRange("H:H")
    .getValues()
    .flat()
    .filter(value => value);
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('htmlAddSO');
  template.customers = customers; // Should be an array of strings
  template.products = products; // Should be an array of strings
  var html = template.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Add New Standing Order');
}

function append(obj) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Standing Orders"))
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Standing Orders"); 
    sheet.appendRow([obj.customer, obj.product, obj.notes]);
}
```

Comment: @DrJekyll_XYZ - Ideas? Yes: define customers!  Double check what customers is being set to before attaching it to the template.  [Use debugger or `console.log`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting).  If you want to check within the template, I find the easiest thing is to dump it into an HTML element for inspection, like `<pre><?= JSON.stringify(customers, null, 2) ?></pre>`. But if you think its undefined in the template, that means we didn't pass it to the template, or what we passed in was undefined, so log it before the template and see.

Comment: I may need my hand holding a little here. im just doing this as a hobby. all im doing before your server side code recommendation is pulling a cell range of values into a variable called customers. should i be converting this prior to setting that variable?

Comment: @DrJekyll_XYZ - OK, done.  Edited my answer to show my best guess as to how to get your values.  YMMV according to what the exact shape of your sheets is like... I just assumed "A:A" in customers is a list of names, and "H:H" in products is a list of product names

Comment: you assumed correctly. i still get the error saying customers not defined. Im looking through the script. I really dont see how it couldnt be defined. we are saying customers = A:A. I know im a bit slow with this im still learning.

Comment: @DrJekyll_XYZ - I did set up sheets with those names and ran it successfully with the code shown.  Check for typos, pay attention to the color highlighting in the editor, use the search utility, use the debugger.  You'll get it.

Comment: Okay that is working perfectly. Super strange. I just deleted the html file created a new one and it works. Thank you ever so much for your patience and your help.

Answer (score 0):

I used most of your code but made a few changes as noted below

GS:

```
function addSO() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//modified sheet name 
  var values=sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");//modified sheet name
  var values1=sh2.getRange(1,8,sh2.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  var t=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah3');//modified html file name
  t.values='['+ values.join(',') + ']';//modified from original passwed as printed strings not arrays
  t.values1='['+ values1.join(',') + ']';//modified from original
  var html=t.evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Add New Standing Order');//made modeless because it's easier for me to debug as I have debug tools avialable in sidebar
}

//Write Standing Order
function writeSO(obj) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3"); 
    sheet.appendRow([obj.selectCustomer, obj.selectProduct, obj.notes]);
}
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
 <form>
 <H2>Select Customer from list</H2>
 <select id="selectCustomer" name="selectCustomer"></select>
<H2>Select Product</H2>
 <select id="selectProduct" name="selectProduct"></select>
<H2>Notes</H2>
<input type="text" size="50" name="notes" id="notes">
<br>
<br>
     <input type="button" value="OK" onClick="submitorder(this.parentNode);" />
</form>
<script>
  console.log('Globals');
  var options= <?!= values ?>;
  options.unshift('Choose a Customer');//I find this easier to put initial value in the array
  //console.log(options);
  var options1= <?!= values1 ?>;//these are passed as printed strings
  options1.unshift('Choose a Product');
  //console.log(options1);

  //added this function
  function updateSelect(vA,id){
      var id=id || 'selectCustomer';
      var select = document.getElementById(id);
      select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i],vA[i]);
      }
  }

//Runs after html is loaded in the page
window.onload=function() {
  updateSelect(options,'selectCustomer');
  updateSelect(options1,'selectProduct');
}

function submitorder(obj) {
 google.script.run
   .withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close();})
   .writeSO(obj);
      }
</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, Thanks for the response. 

That doesnt quite work. It definitely passed the ranges through in a cleaner way so thank you for that.

it doesnt appear to write the options selected and notes back to my sheet. It did however create a new blank row so we are almost there.

Comment: It does on my account.  Did you notice that I changed the names of the sheets to  agree with names I already had.

Comment: Yep. it was pulling the information from my sheets. i changed all the references to them.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting in the browser console.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
and
here was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit"

Comment: Thanks for your help both answers work. I just needed to delete and create new html files for some unknown reason.